# How can i add or remove labels while finetune bert ner model?

Tags: label, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I want to finetune a BERT NER model and remove or add new labels.
For example,
I have these labels:
LOCATION MONEY ORGANIZATION PERSON PRODUCT TIME TVSHOW.

I want more labels or to remove labels while finetuning it. Is this possible? If it is not, what are the other solutions?

I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

BERT enabeles you to do this but you cannot use finetuned model. Such as we tried a finetuned BERTurk model to try this but the architecture of the model did not match with our labels so we decided to try BERTurk original model and it worked. I think BERT can be trained when it is not trained for downstream task such as NER.